# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am brand new to python. I got a error

```
while not cls.isFilled(row,col,myMap):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Would you please instruct how to solve this issue? 
The first "if" check is fine, but "while not" has this error.

```
def main(cls, args):
        ...
        if cls.isFilled(row,col,myMap):
            numCycles = 0

        while not cls.isFilled(row,col,myMap):
            numCycles += 1


def isFilled(cls,row,col,myMap):
        cls.isFilled = True
        ## for-while
        i = 0
        while i < row:
            ## for-while
            j = 0
            while j < col:
                if not myMap[i][j].getIsActive():
                    cls.isFilled = False
                j += 1
            i += 1
        return cls.isFilled
```

Comment: If someone gets similar error with Flask-Login: `current_user.is_authenticated(): TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32750526/1429387).

Comment: Thanks naXa, I would say that the answer you gave is more generally valid for any error like: `is_authenticated(): TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` , not only in Flask but also in Django

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You do `cls.isFilled = True`.  That overwrites the method called `isFilled` and replaces it with the value True.  That method is now gone and you can't call it anymore.  So when you try to call it again you get an error, since it's not there anymore.

The solution is use a different name for the variable than you do for the method.

Answer (score 3):

```
def isFilled(cls,row,col,myMap):
        cls.isFilled = True
```

the error is in here

you have a function/method named **isFilled()** and a attribute of cls instance named **isFilled**, too. Python thinks they are the same

```
def isFilllllllllllllllled(cls,row,col,myMap):
        cls.isFilled = True
```

you can change, for example, as above and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can fix it with following steps -

1. Do `cls.__dict__`
2. This will give you dictionary format output which will contain `{'isFilled':True}` or `{'isFilled':False}` depending upon what you have set.
3. Delete this entry - `del cls.__dict__['isFilled']`
4. You will be able to call the method now.

In this case, we delete the entry which overrides the method as mentioned by BrenBarn.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created an action named `detail` in DRF Viewset.But `detail=True/False` is a property in DRF actions so I just renamed it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. using or setting a var with name cls.isFilled isn't true you must remove cls. and set the name to isFilled
2. you can't use a function in while and if command you can save it in a var and then use that var in the while or if

```python
def main(cls, args):
        ...
        is_filled_fun = isFilled(row,col,myMap)
        if is_filled_fun:
            numCycles = 0

        while not is_filled_fun:
            numCycles += 1


def isFilled(cls,row,col,myMap):
        isFilled = True
        ## for-while
        i = 0
        while i < row:
            ## for-while
            j = 0
            while j < col:
                if not myMap[i][j].getIsActive():
                    isFilled = False
                j += 1
            i += 1
        return isFilled
```