# Flask-Login raises TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable when trying to override is_active property

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I want to modify `is_active` in Flask-Login so that users are not always active.

The default always returns `True`, but I changed it to return the value of the `banned` column.

Based on the docs, `is_active` should be a property.  However, the internal Flask-Login code raises:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

When trying to use `is_active`.

How do I correctly use `is_active` to deactivate some users?

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    banned = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.banned
```

---

```
login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)

if not force and not user.is_active():
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`is_active`, `is_anonymous`, and `is_authenticated` are all properties as of Flask-Login 0.3.  If you want to use them, treat them as attributes, don't call them.  If you want to override them, remember to decorate them with `@property`.

```
# change from
current_user.is_authenticated()
# to
current_user.is_authenticated
```

It appears you are reading the docs for the most recent version (0.3), but using an older version of the library.  Version 0.3 [contains a breaking change](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/CHANGES#L25-L26) which changed these attributes from methods to properties.  You should upgrade to the latest version of Flask-Login and treat them as properties.

You deactivate the user by causing its `is_active` property to return `False`.  Your idea to return the value of a column is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You overload `is_active` to implement your own logic.

What's wrong with it?  Nothing IMO.  It's correct except that you forgot to make it a property using `@property` decorator

In Tornado it's similar to `current_user` for example.

Comment: ok, but i can use def is_banned(self): or anything else. basically this is a property totally independent of flask_login, right?

Comment: Yes, but is_active will be always true in that case. It's all up to your decision